# RTF Line separator

Tags: rtf

Does someone knows how to insert a horizontal line separator in a RTF file?

Example:

*some text*

---

*some other text*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the `\dpline` commands (See the section on "Drawing Objects" on page 157 in the [RTF Spec 1.9.1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=dd422b8d-ff06-4207-b476-6b5396a18a2b&displaylang=en)).

Here's a sample that should do what you want:

```
{\rtf1
{\pard some text.\par}
{\pard {\*\do\dobxcolumn\dobypara\dodhgt
        \dpline\dpxsize9200\dplinesolid\dplinew30}\par}
{\pard some other text.\par}
}
```

**RTF Output Preview:** [image: RTF Output Preview]

You customize the line color with `\dplineco[rgb]`, width with `\dplinew`), line-styles etc.

And if you're interested in RTF, you would find the [RTF Pocket Guide](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596004750/) helpful -- it is much less boring than the RTF Spec! Specifically, it talks about other ways of drawing a horizontal line.

Comment: Great! I just bought the book: thank you for this advice witch will be a great help ;)

Comment: @AshutoshMehra this won't render the line for me in OS X TextEdit.App which I had thought was a full-featured RTF editor. Which editor are you folks using? Any idea why I can't produce a line with these commands in my editor?

Comment: I have the same problem as @TeXnewbie; macOS's rendering approach doesn't seem to treat this as anything; I just see a blank space.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need a simple horizontal rule you can also try this:

```
{\pard \brdrb \brdrs\brdrw10\brsp20 {\fs4\~}\par \pard}
```

Comment: what text editor are you using? When I try this in OS X TextEdit.App, the editor does not render anything that looks like a line or horizontal rule.

Answer (score 0):

Here's code to draw a line at any arbitrary angle:

```
{\rtf1
{\shp
{\shpinst \shpbxpage \shpbypage \shpleft200 \shptop400 \shpright3000 \shpbottom2000
{\sp{\sn shapeType}{\sv 32}}
}}}
```

See RTF spec. for 'shapeType' options.

As I begin to learn RTF, it appears that '\do' draw objects are of limited use, and '\shp' is the way to go. For instance, you can only do horizontal lines with \dpline. You can't suppress the rectangle (zero line width) around \dptxbx. Neither \dptxbx nor \dptxbxtext will obey \fittext.

Comment: On macOS, this just renders "shapeType32"

Answer (score 0):

I've just successfully made a convincing horizontal rule in Apple's Textedit by: insert a table, set the cols and rows to 1 (change the colour of the border at this point if you want) type a single character (a space) in the cell, select it and open the font palette, set font size to 0.2

Comment: This was a coding question so your answer is not very relevant, but thank you anyway :-)